# Don't understand why I'm getting an index error

Tags: python

Don't understand why I'm getting tuple error out of range.
Please Help

```
contactname_1 = input('Enter the 1st contact name:')
contactnum_1 = input('Enter the 1st contact phone number: ')
contactmail_1 = input('Enter the 1st contact email: ')

contactname_2 = input('Enter the 2nd contact name: ')
contactnum_2 = input('Enter the 2nd contact phone number: ')
contactmail_2 = input('Enter the 2nd contact email: ')

Display_align = input('Enter display alignment left/right/center (L/R/C)?')

if (Display_align == 'L'):
  print('{0:<30} {1:<30} {2:<30}'.format('Name' + 'Phone' + 'Email'))
  print('{0:<30} {1:<30} {2:<30}'.format(contactname_1, contactnum_1, contactmail_1))
  print('{0:<30} {1:<30} {2:<30}'.format(contactname_2, contactnum_2, contactmail_2))
```

Comment: You mean `format('Name', 'Phone', 'Email')`, so 3 strings, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

You concatenate strings when you pass them as args to format.
Here is the corrected version:

```
print('{0:<30} {1:<30} {2:<30}'.format('Name', 'Phone', 'Email'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first print statement, you need a tuple of three in the format method. Adding 'Name', 'Phone' and 'Email' gives a single string. Replace

```
print('{0:<30} {1:<30} {2:<30}'.format('Name' + 'Phone' + 'Email'))
```

with

```
print('{0:<30} {1:<30} {2:<30}'.format('Name', 'Phone','Email'))
```